# MySQL, What is SQL interface?

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

[image]

Hi. I'm studying MySQL.
From MySQL architecture diagram, what is SQL interface? and difference from Parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Interface as diagram says consists of multiple components. Basically those are queries like

```
SELECT * FROM table_x;

ALTER TABLE table_x DROP COLUMN column_x;

GRANT ALL ON db_x.* TO 'user_x'@'host_x';
```

Later those queries are handled by parser, optimizer etc.